# polyglossia plus fancyhdr plus MakeUppercase leads to an error with polyglossia

Tags: fancyhdr, polyglossia

I have a document where I had been using `polyglossia` for languages and `fancyhdr` to customize the header. This has worked for several years, but something must have updated, and now I get this error: `! Package polyglossia Error: language ENGLISH is not loaded. Please load it before using it..`.

After poking around, I've narrowed the problem down to the combination of `polyglossia`, `fancyhdr`, and `\MakeUppercase`. If I remove `\MakeUppercase` from the MWE below, everything is fine—except that I want to uppercase the header information. I would appreciate any suggestions.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{book}

\usepackage[nolocalmarks]{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage[variant=medieval]{latin}
\setotherlanguage[variant=ancient]{greek}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead[RO, LE]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[CE]{\MakeUppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[CO]{\MakeUppercase{\rightmark}}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{{\textenglish{#1}}}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}{}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Whatever}

\section{Something}
\lipsum[1-5]

\section{Something else}
\lipsum[6-10]

\chapter{Whatever else}

\section{Foo}
\lipsum[11-15]

\section{Bar}
\lipsum[16-20]

\end{document}
```

Two notes to save time for people who want to help:

1. `\uppercase` doesn't cause the error, but it also doesn't do anything. It seems to be ignored.
2. [`\textcase`](https://ctan.org/pkg/textcase)'s `\MakeTextUppercase` causes the same error as `\MakeUppercase`, presumably because it's just a wrapper for `\MakeUppercase`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move `\MakeUppercase` to `\chaptermark` and `\sectionmark`.

```latex
\fancyhead[CE]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[CO]{\rightmark}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{{\textenglish{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{}}
```

Comment: I feel pretty foolish now. Thanks.